# Mask values that are not in sort order in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have a complex calculation which I expect the result to be an array where values are in sorted order. However, because of numerical errors at some critical points, some resulting values are wrong. I'd like to mask those values. How should I do that?

Here is an equivalent function, but that assume values are sorted from highest to lowers, and that outsiders are always greater than the expected value. I wonder if there is a simpler and more efficient way to do this.

```
def maskoutsiders(a):
    mask = numpy.zeros(len(a))
    lastval = a[0]
    for i in range(1, len(a)):
        if a[i] > lastval:
            mask[i] = 1
        else:
            lastval = a[i]

    return ma.masked_array(a, mask=mask)
```

Comment: So, starting at index 0, you want to pick out the indices which mark a strictly increasing subsequence of the array (and mask the other indices)? E.g. `[3,1,2,4,5]` would be `[True, False, False, True, True]`?

Comment: Yes! Also, there are only a few bad values, but these bad values could be in groups of 2 or 3. Also, in ma, 1 is masked, and 0 in unmasked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When `a` is supposed to be decreasing, you can use:

```
mask = a > np.minimum.accumulate(a)
```

and when `a` is supposed to be increasing, you can use:

```
mask = a < np.maximum.accumulate(a)
```

(`np` is `numpy`.)

For example,

```
In [44]: def mymaskoutsiders(a):
   ....:     mask = a > np.minimum.accumulate(a)
   ....:     return ma.masked_array(a, mask=mask)
   ....:
```

Compare the results with this array:

```
In [100]: x
Out[100]: array([ 13. ,  16.5,  15.5,  11.5,   6. ,   9.5,   5.5,   9. ,   5. ,   2.5])
```

Here's your function:

```
In [101]: maskoutsiders(x)
Out[101]: 
masked_array(data = [13.0 -- -- 11.5 6.0 -- 5.5 -- 5.0 2.5],
             mask = [False  True  True False False  True False  True False False],
       fill_value = 1e+20)
```

And here's my version:

```
In [102]: mymaskoutsiders(x)
Out[102]: 
masked_array(data = [13.0 -- -- 11.5 6.0 -- 5.5 -- 5.0 2.5],
             mask = [False  True  True False False  True False  True False False],
       fill_value = 1e+20)
```